# Export eclipse console view output to text file

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

How to redirect console view output to a text file in Eclipse?

Answer (score 44):

> Run -> Run Configurations... -> Java
>   Application -> Your Application ->
>   Common tab -> File
>
> Check **Append** for append mode.

Comment: Wich only works if you run a Java application. What if you need to save the console output of the build?

Comment: @Martin - For me it worked also as a C++ application (with the respective IDE). Have not tried though the build phase...

Answer (score 13):

Go to Run --> Run Configurations..

In the dialog, select your Java project, then select the Common tab.

First, you have to select the Output File Checkbox.
Then set the path and filename where Eclipse is going to redirect the console output.

Second, select Append Checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I would just like to add that if you don't select the Append checkbox, then the contents of this file will be overwritten during each build which is what I actually prefer instead of appending each output at the end of the file.