# In Eclipse Plug-in development how to redirect console view output to a text file

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Eclipse Plug-in development how to redirect console view output to a text file.

Comment: Just for your development purpose or for the user of your plug-in?

Comment: Is it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415260/export-eclipse-console-view-output-to-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the `System.out` and `System.err` streams you should use the `System.setErr()` and `System.setOut()` functions. They both take a `PrintStream` object as a parameter. In Eclipse I tend to dump this to a scrolling text view so pass this my model I'm sure you can build this to send it to a text file instead.