# How to get Eclipse to keep console output?

Tags: eclipse, console

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Win XP with Java 6.  I have a Maven project with GWT (2.3), and when I launch my project (Run -> Web Application), the app is throwing some startup errors.  However, the console is only preserving the last part of the errors, and I can't tell what started it all off.

http://screencast.com/t/MsgM1SuxI

Notice in the screen shot, I've scrolled up as much as possible but still the stack trace is cut off.  How can I get Eclipse to save the entire console error log?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: What happens if you toggle the scroll lock, I believe it would then preserve the error log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the capacity of the Eclipse output console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828255/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-the-eclipse-output-console)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can adjust Eclipse's console buffer size in the preferences. See http://codeyarns.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/eclipse-console-buffer-size/:

[image]

Comment: We want to "keep" i.e. save it to a file, not just extend its buffer size. (Preferably for me, I'd like console output for Build All to be saved automatically.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5415260/217893 for how to also pipe it to a file.